Parts of model missing in Unity, but faces are all pointing the right way,
I made a model in Blender and imported to Unity. It was working fine in Unity, until I added a small trim top and bottom. For some reason, this breaks the model and causes these small but obvious connecting triangles to vanish. When selected in Unity the object acts as if the missing parts are holes.
I've tried this on an alternate version of the model, and the same thing happened. Feels like a bug.

I've checked culling and they're pointed the right way.
I've tried deleting and redoing them.
I've tried redoing the UVs

Nothing really seems to help. Is there a solution to this?





It turns out the wall had a lot of random materials linked to it that I thought I had removed. Just right click them and then unlink.

